# Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, core-graphics

Getting error:

> Argument labels `(_:, _:)` do not match any available overloads

in:

```
snap = UISnapBehavior(
    item: self, 
    snapToPoint: CGPoint(CGRectGetMidX(movement), CGRectGetMidY(movement))
)
```

How do I solve this error in Swift?

Comment: `CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(movement), y: CGRectGetMidY(movement))` note the parameters name `x:` `y:` that it is missing from your initializer

Comment: *"How do i solve this error in swift?"* – if everything else fails, looking up the  documentation might help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpoint

Comment: Type just the `CGPoint(` and then look at what autocomplete suggests for available initializers.

Answer (score 1):

Because CGPoint requires the argument labels to be present ensure that you have them along with your initializer.

```
let midX = CGRectGetMidX(movement)
let midY = CGRectGetMidy(movement)

let point = CGPoint(x: midX , y: midY) // x & y Argument Labels Required With CGPoint Initializer
```